# Is it possible to hide the ContextualBalloon without removing the view from the DOM?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a situation where a toolbar item in CKEditor5 opens a ContextualBalloon which contains an iframe.

In my current understanding, the only way to hide the balloon is to remove the iframe view i.e.

`this.balloon.remove(this.colorPickerIframeView)`

However this removes the iframe view from the DOM, meaning that the next time I open the balloon view the iframe is reloaded.

I'd rather not have to reload the iframe every time, is there any way around that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only hide the `ContextualBalloon`'s view you can try to use [`this.balloon.view.hide()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_panel_balloon_balloonpanelview-BalloonPanelView.html#function-hide)